# How to decrypt Vetx WebClient response automatically

Tags: java, rest, ssl, jersey, vert.x

I have a web client to call some REST API which is running over https using Vertx WebClient. The response received from the server is in encrypted format. How to decrypt it automatically? Do I need to install SSL certificates of the server in my JVM to do this? I have a similar client written using Jersey rest client library which is automatically decrypting the response without installing the any certificates in JVM where I can see the proper response from the same API

```
 this.client.post(“some/url”) 
                .putHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
                .putHeader("Content-Length", "10")
                .putHeader("User-Agent", "Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.4; SAMSUNG-SM-N900A Build/KTU84P)")
                .putHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive")
                .putHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip")
                .sendBuffer(Buffer.buffer("abcde"))              
                .subscribe().with(r -> {
                    System.out.println(String.format("Subscribe: code:%d body:%s",r.statusCode(), r.bodyAsString()));                
              });
```

The above code is printing decrypted message on console something like below.

:��mo���B�����%�Ʋ�(�e�������mФ  b�ؠ��s9�^J�d�@g,s�gν�\�������z�}��~��Hy6[><�����������r����ο|]�=���)'�u�����{��_��w�����ϸ<��/�>N��������+�ݗۯ��s�wy�����f��z����"$�����o��ý���h��n��V��b��ۉ�=ܟ?���tRF�M�~��c���C�G�B�����u��n�~~����6����G�ZH��   �I�����H8������c��/6���հ�㣦`�V�ZN
,���[\��a���SQ��P\la���

Comment: Is it that it just needs to be decompressed? You are saying with the Accpet-Encoding that you want the response in gzip. Does whatever client you are using automatically decompress gzip responses? What happens if you remove the Accept-Encoding header?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha, you are right...if I remove the Accept-Encoding header I can see the proper response with Vertx web client now. But when using Jersey client even with Accept-Encoding header it is able to automatically decompress gzip. Thank you for noting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding the `Accept-Encoding` header manually, configure the client so that [compression handling](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/web/client/WebClientOptions.html#setTryUseCompression-boolean-) is enabled:

```
WebClientOptions options = new WebClientOptions().setTryUseCompression(true);
```